# Get key name from the property of javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, key

How can I get the key name "email" inside the function ? Is there a special context variable to do this ?

Thanks for help.

```js
var user = {
  "email": function() {
    // How can I get the name of the key (email) inside the function ?
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to really know the name/key of the function without hard coding it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately anonymous functions are _just that_, anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

A [relatively new feature of JS](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation) will assign a name to an anonymous function expression based on the variable or property to which it is initially assigned.

You can access a function's name via `arguments.callee.name`

```js
var bar = {
  baz: function() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
  }
}

bar.baz();
```

Of course, if you copy the function elsewhere, it won't get a new name. The name is given to it at the time it is created.

```js
var bar = {
  baz: function() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
  }
}

bar.foo = bar.baz;

bar.foo();
```

Comment: Thank you for tips but for arguments.callee.name, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this by asking a question. Consider this scenario:

```
let myFunc = function(){ /* somehow returns the name */ };

let a = {
    funcA: myFunc
};

let b = {
    funcB: myFunc
};
```

Now, consider this:

```
a.funcA();
b.funcB();
```

What should they return? `myFunc`, `funcA`, or `funcB`? The answer is "it doesn't make sense".

This is why what you are trying to do is impossible. The function can be "owned" by different objects.